# SQL Server Truncates variables but throws error while insert into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider a table : dummy

```
DROP TABLE dummy;
CREATE TABLE dummy( name nvarchar( 200 ));
```

Try to insert data larger than 200 nvarchar length ( that is 400 1 byte chars). It throws error: (good)

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Now try to do similar on a variable.

```
declare @txt nvarchar(200) = 'period:daily?h=2&m=5|period:daily?h=1&m=14|period:daily?h=1&m=16|period:daily?h=1&m=23|period:daily?h=1&m=37|period:daily?h=1&m=17|period:daily?h=1&m=9|period:daily?h=1&m=25|period:daily?h=1&m=28|period:daily?h=1&m=0|period:daily?h=1&m=2|period:daily?h=1&m=52';
select @txt;
```

Now the select output is : ( Observe that the output is truncated to fit into variable @txt )

```
period:daily?h=2&m=5|period:daily?h=1&m=14|period:daily?h=1&m=16|period:daily?h=1&m=23|period:daily?h=1&m=37|period:daily?h=1&m=17|period:daily?h=1&m=9|period:daily?h=1&m=25|period:daily?h=1&m=28|peri
```

So my question is, why does the variable values are truncated but not the table inserts?

This is potentially an issues as any SP using variable to store value from a table T1 Column1 and insert into T2 column1 after some checks will partially loose the data present in T1 Column1 )

Shouldn't the logic to handle larger length data be same in both the case to keep the behavior consistent?

Example:

```
DROP TABLE dummy;
CREATE TABLE dummy( name nvarchar( 200 ));

DROP TABLE dummy_realdata;
CREATE TABLE dummy_realdata( name nvarchar( 2048 ));

INSERT INTO dummy_realdata
VALUES( 'period:daily?h=2&m=5|period:daily?h=1&m=14|period:daily?h=1&m=16|period:daily?h=1&m=23|period:daily?h=1&m=37|period:daily?h=1&m=17|period:daily?h=1&m=9|period:daily?h=1&m=25|period:daily?h=1&m=28|period:daily?h=1&m=0|period:daily?h=1&m=2|period:daily?h=1&m=52' );

declare @txt nvarchar(200);
select @txt = name from dummy_realdata ;
insert into dummy values( @txt);
select * from dummy ; -- truncated. hence lose of data!
select * from dummy_realdata ; -- Real data
```

Comment: The unsatisfactory answer is that it's [*documented*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176089.aspx) to do so: "When character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, values that are too long for the new data type are truncated"

Comment: Yeah, I read the document. But isn't this error prone? As I did face this issue of data lose. I agree that the SP and Table should be corrected, but still the inconsistent behavior is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simple if you can look at table dummy_realdata.name size  is 2048. Try vice versa i.e insert into dummy and then dummy_realdata you will face same issue. Because the length of your insertion name is approximately 258. But you requested to store only 200.

Try this to get rid

```
DROP TABLE dummy;
CREATE TABLE dummy( name nvarchar( 2048 ));

DROP TABLE dummy_realdata;
CREATE TABLE dummy_realdata( name nvarchar( 2048 ));

INSERT INTO dummy_realdata
VALUES( 'period:daily?h=2&m=5|period:daily?h=1&m=14|period:daily?h=1&m=16|period:daily?h=1&m=23|period:daily?h=1&m=37|period:daily?h=1&m=17|period:daily?h=1&m=9|period:daily?h=1&m=25|period:daily?h=1&m=28|period:daily?h=1&m=0|period:daily?h=1&m=2|period:daily?h=1&m=52' );

declare @txt nvarchar(2048);
select @txt = name from dummy_realdata ;
insert into dummy values( @txt);
select * from dummy ; -- truncated. hence lose of data!
select * from dummy_realdata ; -- Real data
```

Comment: My question is why the data is truncated for variables but not while inserting. Assume that I can't change DDL of tables. Because I have faced this issue when no exception was thrown and I see the wrong that in Table2

Comment: Dude your dummy_realdata is nvarchar(2048), @txt is nvarchar(200) and  dummy is nvarchar(200). But you are inserting string of length 250. Try directly inserting the string in dummy table you will again face the same truncation error. It is not variable or table here it is size of data type.

Comment: For more clarity reduce the size of dummy_realdata to 200 and check you can see the same truncation in this table also. And be informed SQL server will never throw error for this kind of truncation.

Comment: No, I have already tried inserting directly into Dummy and it threw error but doesn't truncate, its mentioned my question.

Comment: Yes you are right, but variable truncates the name and then inserts.

Comment: That's my question. Why there is an inconsistent behavior?

Comment: That is due to implicit conversion by SQL Server.

Comment: To have the same behaviour try SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF and try directly inserting into table without variable.

Comment: But still the data is lost right? I would rather like it throwing the error which lets the caller understand. But truncating the variable with no warning is bad!

Comment: Then remove varialble and directly insert the data. May be the coder has done this so that he should not get an error while insertion. Because I cannot see any purpose for this variable in the code.

Comment: One think I want to remember you is you have capacity to store only 200 chars then how can you expect SQL Server to store more than that

Comment: I don't expect it to store, I expect it to tell me that I am trying to store more than 200.

Comment: Then instead of using variable directly store the data in table it will pop the error.